# Deja Dup Ubutu 16.04 Deja Dup back up fails

Tags: 16.04, backup, deja-dup

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.  Deja Dup  back up fails to load with message `Failed to execute child process "duplicity"`. No such file or directory. Reboot and reload makes no difference.

When I click on Deja Dup I get a box with the message:

```
Back Up Failed
Failed to execute child process"duplicity". 
No such file or directory.
```

Close

How can this be overcome so that I can backup files?

Comment: What's the output of `which duplicity` and `apt-cache policy deja-dup duplicity`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 17.04. After I ran command:

```
sudo apt-cache policy deja-dup duplicity
```

I saw in terminal output that duplicity is not installed. So I installed it with apt.

```
sudo apt-get install duplicity
```

And error was successfully solved. Hope it helps you too.